# Angular *ngFor variable scope for event handler

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have just started learning Angular and found out that the ngFor is placed on the child element that should repeat instead of the parent element (e.g. a list of elements that repeat).

```
<select  class="form-control" id="sel {{order.product.id}}">
  <option (click)="this.unsetProductSize(order)" selected>Select size...</option>
  <option (click)="this.setProductSize(order, size.id, size.size, size.stock)" *ngFor="let size of order.product.productSize">{{size.size}}</option>
</select>
```

So the issue here is that the "click" event handler will only work on Firefox. It is not the right way to do this as the handler should be on the select element (parent) and must be a "change" event handler.

The variable scope from the ngFor ("size") will be outside of scope if I  move the functions to the select element. I need each function to be executed for each product as I will have multiple select elements. My question is, is there a known way to solve this, or maybe a for each that is placed on the parent element instead of the child?

Comment: i think there is extra space

Comment: @NegiRox yeah that is my bad, sorry. It showed no effect when I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect use for `[(ngModel)]`. Also use `[ngValue]` to capture the whole object chosen. Also you don't need the function `unsetProductSize`, since you can use `setProductSize` to check if value exists or not. Also, don't use `this` in template. So all in all, I suggest the following:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedSize" (ngModelChange)="setProductSize(order)">
  <option [ngValue]="null">Select size...</option>
  <option [ngValue]="size" *ngFor="let size of order.product.productSize">
    {{size.size}}
  </option>
</select>
```

TS:

```ts
selectedSize = null;

setProductSize(order) {
  console.log(order) // order here
  if (this.selectedSize) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // do other stuff!
  }
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrigvw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work using your solution. It makes more sense that angular is used this way.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<select  class="form-control" id="sel {{order.product.id}}" (change)="handleProductSizeChange($event)">
  <option [value]="null" selected>Select size...</option>
  <option [value]="size" *ngFor="let size of order.product.productSize">{{size.size}}</option>
</select>
```

every option has a value and a single handler for option changes is used at a `select` element

Comment: How can I extract the value (object size) from the event passed to the handleProductSizeChange($event)?

Comment: `$event.target.value` should return you the value from the selected option

Comment: The size object that I receive seems to be an empty object and console logs it as [object Object]. When I try to access the properties, it says undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can and the click event on the select box. please refer following code

```
<select  class="form-control" (click)="setProductSize(order, $event.target.value)"  id="sel {{order.product.id}}">
  <option selected value="0">Select size...</option>
  <option  *ngFor="let size of order.product.productSize" [value]="size">{{size.size}}</option>
</select>
```

In the .ts file, you can write your functionality

```
setProductSize(order, size){
//You have whole order object in order variable and selected size object in size variable
//if user click on Select size... option in size variable you will get the value 0. you can add condition according to the selected values
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The size object that I receive seems to be an empty object and console logs it as [object Object]. When I try to access the properties, it says undefined.

Comment: Use JSON. stringify() to print the object